# Pyspark StringIndexer throwing 'unseen label' error when indexing columns in a Dataframe and getting the count of rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, indexing, bigdata

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I am indexing 2 columns - ID and Entity_ID. After the indexing I run the count operation but the last stage is failing with the error -

```
`unseen label: 00000167dea2e045a67f8695b0143e14. To handle unseen labels, set Param handleInvalid to keep.`
```

I can't understand the error as I am not using the StringIndexer to transform a different dataframe. I am fitting and transforming on the same data.
Here is a snippet of code I'm running that is eventually failing.

Dataframe name before operation - final_df

```
idx_model_1 = StringIndexer(inputCol="id", outputCol="id_index")
idx_model_2 = StringIndexer(inputCol="entity_id", outputCol="entity_id_index")
df=idx_model_1.transform(final_df)
df=idx_model_2.transform(df)

df.count()
```

What could be the reason for this error?
The pyspark version I'm using is '2.4.4.4.1.8.29'